# What instruments are used as the lead in the Naruto Storm video game series? [link provided]

Tags: instruments

I am sorry if this is a bad or annoying question to ask, especially since I am not too good at describing what I mean. But let's take [this example](https://youtu.be/mjuinmiZji8).

The first 13 seconds we have a slow piano playing, then this pieces blows off with a "high" playing instrument that leads the melody. I mean that instrument. What is it? Or at least how do I recreate those sounds to use in my own works?

Not sure if it is the same, but [this soundtrack](https://youtu.be/rufY11xWCBI) also uses a very similar instrument to create dramatic sounding music.

I would really like to know how they are done.

Answer (score 1):

In the link you provided the lead instrument is a violin, possibly the lead violinist (concertmaster in the US) of the orchestra playing at the same time.

Comment: Violin! Of course! I am so dumb.